# "Not authorized, token failed"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, chat, mern

I am getting an error in Postman while running the messaging API, "**Not authorized, token failed**"

This is my message.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const { protect } = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");
const {sendMessage} = require("../controllers/messageControllers");

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").post(protect, sendMessage); //compilation would start from here

module.exports = router;
```

I have made a JWT secret key

This is my generate token file

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const generateToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "30d",
    });
};

module.exports = generateToken;
```

This is my authMiddleware.js file

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let token;

    if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")){
        try{
            token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(401);
            throw new Error("Not authorized, token failed");
        }
    }

    if(!token){
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("No token, no authorization");
    }
});

module.exports = {protect};
```

The token was working till last week and now it is showing invalid. The token should work or how can I create a new token for my project?

Comment: Did you create the token 30 days ago and never renew it? It has a 30 day expiration so after that it won’t work anymore and you need to generate a new one like you did before.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working last week but now it is not recognizing it, the JWT_SECRET environment variable has probably changed, make sure the value was the same as last week, or create a new one (check that the JWT_SECRET variable is not null or undefined).

About this part:

```js
req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");
```

Also check your user database as the user may no longer exist.